# Report Validation Failed on Pentaho BI Server

Tags: pentaho, report-designer

I'm trying to publish this PRD file that I created and it works on my machine when I do a preview. But when I pusblish it to the server it returns "Report validation failed".

The prpt file uses a transformation as a source, and that transformation looks into an excel file that changes daily.

My assumption the BI server is having some problems working out the report is that the sources files that are used are accessed locally on my computer. So I changed the access type to UNC path. While using UNC, I tested it on my machine and it still works. I published it to the server and I still get the same error.

Any suggestions other than looking at the log file of the server?

Comment: you did your database connection with server? the same way you did for creating file?

Comment: there some posibilities : 1. Wrong DB COnnection, 2. User doesn't have authority to access this report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have sub-reports on your report, check if you changed the connection on each sub-report.

Comment: And if you are using an Olap cube as Data Set, check if the schema is updated (at least I have this problems when I tried to public my local report. I hope it helps).

Answer (score 2):

If you have defined any parameters check those parameter's properties (Double click on the parameter fields) there is some check boxes , untick the check box and check whether its  working or not. if it is working check your parameters that you have defined.